# android-Staying on same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have lots of button that refers other activities,but when I click one of them it opens the activities on another page.For example if I click 10 button that refers 10 different activities,those activies will open in 10 different pages.I wanted to do it within one page no other page,but I don't know how to do it.So any suggesttion will be appreciated.
These are classes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T28H.png)

These are xml's:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoXUD.png)

And this is my mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView mImageView;
private Button mButton;
private ImageButton mButton2;
private Button mButton3;
private Button mButton4;
private Button mButton5;
private Button mButton6;
private CirclePageIndicator indicator;
private CirclePageIndicator indicator2;
private CirclePageIndicator indicator3;
private CirclePageIndicator indicator4;
private static ViewPager mPager;
private static ViewPager mPager2;
private static ViewPager mPager3;
private static ViewPager mPager4;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private static int currentPage2 = 0;
private static int currentPage3 = 0;
private static int currentPage4 = 0;
private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter2;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter3;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter4;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter5;
List<String> listDataHeader2;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild2;
List<String> listDataHeader3;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild3;
List<String> listDataHeader4;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild4;
List<String> listDataHeader5;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild5;
ExpandableListView expListView;
ExpandableListView expListView2;
ExpandableListView expListView3;
ExpandableListView expListView4;
ExpandableListView expListView5;
ExpandableListView expListView6;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private static final Integer[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.one_full, R.drawable.two_full, R.drawable.three_full, R.drawable.four_full, R.drawable.five_full, R.drawable.six_full, R.drawable.seven_full};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static final Integer[] IMAGES2 = {R.drawable.bir_bir, R.drawable.bir_iki, R.drawable.bir_uc};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static final Integer[] IMAGES3 = {R.drawable.iki_bir, R.drawable.iki_iki, R.drawable.iki_uc};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static final Integer[] IMAGES4 = {R.drawable.uc_bir, R.drawable.uc_iki, R.drawable.uc_uc};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] items = {"diğer","iletişim",  "sss", "online işlem merkezi"};
String[] items2 = {"İnternet","Sonet ADSL","Sonet Fiber",  "Sonet Yalın İnternet", "Sonet Uydu İnternet"};
String[] items3 = {"Cihazlar","Modem"};
String[] items4 = {"Kampanyalar","Sonet ADSL",  "Sonet Fiber", "Sonet Yalın İnternet","Sonet Uydu İnternet"};
String[] items5 = {"Destek","Fatura İşlemleri",  "Satış Noktaları", "Bize Ulaşın","Sosyal Medya Sonet","Bölge Çözüm Ortaklığı"};
String[] items6 = {"diğer","iletişim",  "sss", "online işlem merkezi"};
String[] items7 = {"diğer","iletişim",  "sss", "online işlem merkezi"};
String[] items8 = {"diğer","iletişim",  "sss", "online işlem merkezi"};





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    mImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 205));
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cihazlar);
    mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    mButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    mButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.internet);
    mButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.servisler);
    mButton4.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    mButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kampanya);
    mButton5.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    mButton6= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mButton6.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(25,25,112));
    mButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, mButton6);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();//showing popup menu
        }
    });

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Cihazlar.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Internet.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Servisler.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Kampanya.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });







    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES.length; i++)
        ImagesArray.add(IMAGES[i]);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this, ImagesArray));

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES2.length; i++)
        ImagesArray2.add(IMAGES2[i]);

    mPager2 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
    mPager2.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this, ImagesArray2));

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES3.length; i++)
        ImagesArray3.add(IMAGES3[i]);

    mPager3 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager3);
    mPager3.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this, ImagesArray3));

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES4.length; i++)
        ImagesArray4.add(IMAGES4[i]);

    mPager4 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager4);
    mPager4.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this, ImagesArray4));

    indicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    indicator2 = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator2);
    indicator2.setViewPager(mPager2);
    indicator3 = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator3);
    indicator3.setViewPager(mPager3);
    indicator4 = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator4);
    indicator4.setViewPager(mPager4);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    indicator.setRadius(3 * density);


    NUM_PAGES = IMAGES.length;

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            if (currentPage2 == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage2 = 0;
            }
            mPager2.setCurrentItem(currentPage2++, true);
            if (currentPage3 == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage3 = 0;
            }
            mPager3.setCurrentItem(currentPage3++, true);
            if (currentPage4 == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage4 = 0;
            }
            mPager4.setCurrentItem(currentPage4++, true);

        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);

    // Pager listener over indicator
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });
    indicator2.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage2 = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });
    indicator3.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage3 = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });
    indicator4.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage4 = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });


    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    expListView2 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp2);
    expListView3 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp3);
    expListView4 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp4);
    expListView5 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp5);


    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listAdapter2 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader2, listDataChild2);
    listAdapter3 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader3, listDataChild3);
    listAdapter4 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader4, listDataChild4);
    listAdapter5 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader5, listDataChild5);



    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    expListView2.setAdapter(listAdapter3);
    expListView3.setAdapter(listAdapter4);
    expListView4.setAdapter(listAdapter5);
    expListView5.setAdapter(listAdapter2);

    expListView5.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 4) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Internet.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (groupPosition == 7) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), subelerimiz.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    expListView5.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_adsl.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_fiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_yalin_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_uydu_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_tum_paketler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_hizmet_karsilastirma.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 7) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_diger_internet_hizmetleri.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 8) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_paket_sihirbazi.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 1) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_guvenlik.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_bulut_bilisim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_mobil_servisler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_sonet_teknoloji.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 2) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_adsl.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_airfiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_fiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_yalin_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_uydu_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_tablet_hediye.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 3) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_guvenli_evim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_guvenli_isim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_akilli_evim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_akilli_isim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_sonet_akilli_tv.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 5) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cihazlar_sonet_musterilerine_ozel.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 6) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_fatura_islemleri.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_satis_noktalari.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_bize_ulasin.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TV.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_iletisim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_sosyal_medya_sonet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_bolge_cozum_ortakligi.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 7) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 8) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), online_islem_merkezi.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_adsl.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_fiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_yalin_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_uydu_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_tum_paketler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_hizmet_karsilastirma.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 7) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_diger_internet_hizmetleri.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 8) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_paket_sihirbazi.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    expListView2.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_guvenlik.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_bulut_bilisim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_mobil_servisler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_sonet_teknoloji.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    expListView3.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cihazlar_sonet_musterilerine_ozel.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    expListView4.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Senindunyan.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cihazlar_sonet_musterilerine_ozel.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Destek.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    // To make ExpandableListView scrollable in the ScrollView
    expListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
    // To make ExpandableListView scrollable in the ScrollView
    expListView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override



}
```

}

Comment: I couldn't add it all because only 30000 char limit

Comment: Learn about fragments

Comment: Yes ..Using of Fragment is the best way to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after every startActivity(intent);

yourActivityName.this.finish();

and on back pressed call the previous activity you wish to go to.

Comment: Thank you.This is what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome, mark the answer as correct! and happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments instead of activities. Your main activity should define a `<FrameLayout>` in its xml and on each button click push a fragment to this `<Framelayout>`.